# Extract an SDL_Texture from a source SDL_Texture

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have the following function that extracts a 64x64 pixel texture from a bigger texture tiled with them:

```
SDL_Texture* cropTexture (SDL_Texture* src, int x, int y)
{
    SDL_Texture* dst = SDL_CreateTexture(gRenderer, gSurface->format->format, SDL_TEXTUREACCESS_TARGET, 64, 64);
    SDL_Rect rect = {64 * x, 64 * y, 64, 64};
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(gRenderer, dst);
    SDL_RenderCopy(gRenderer, src, &rect, NULL);

    return dst;
}
```

Now, when I call the function like this:

```
SDL_Texture* txt_walls [3];
txt_walls[0] = cropTexture (allWalls, 0, 0);
txt_walls[1] = cropTexture (allWalls, 0, 1);
txt_walls[2] = cropTexture (allWalls, 4, 3);
```

then `txt_walls[2]` results in a black texture (or at least, uninitialized).

When I add one meaningless line of code to that:

```
SDL_Texture* txt_walls [3];
txt_walls[0] = cropTexture (allWalls, 0, 0);
txt_walls[1] = cropTexture (allWalls, 0, 1);
txt_walls[2] = cropTexture (allWalls, 4, 3);
cropTexture (allWalls, 1, 1); // whatever, ignore the returned object
```

then txt_walls[2] is correct: the texture at this array position renders just fine in my program.

What is wrong with `cropTexture`? I'm new in both C++ and SDL2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the render target back to default after you have cropped the texure, otherwise it will continue to draw on the texture. Add this before the `return` in `cropTexture`:

```
SDL_SetRenderTarget(gRenderer, NULL);
```

Comment: Stupid that I didn't think of that. This is correct.